# How do i change the color of the text to white instead of black in this CSS file

Tags: css, forms, webforms

I have this css file. how do I change the text to white instead of black?

```
#contactform {
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
#contactform .captch span{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}


#contactform .form {
    text-align:left; 
    font-size:18px; 
    font-weight:normal; 
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#666;
}

#contactform input.text,textarea.text, select.text {
    padding:5px; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    background: url(images/input-bg.gif) top left no-repeat; 
}

#contactform #result {
    color:#FF0000;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
#contactform .message {
    padding: 5px 3px;
}

#contactform img.loading-img {
    padding: 5px 3px;
}

#contactform textarea.text {
    height:100px;
}

#contactform input#submit {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
#contactform table , #contactform tr td , #contactform tr{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The colour of which text?

Comment: Please consider re-formatting your question, it's unclear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow

I may suggest that you could, for further questions, take other users potings as a sample for your own. Your posting is very confusing and badly formatted.

CSS property for white text is `color: #ffffff ;`

The following link is a good information source on css https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS

Edit:

Looks better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use all the Fs:

```
color:#FFFFFF;
```

Or, shorthand:

```
color:#fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have the text color white on your whole page add:

`color: #fff;` to your html,body like this:

```
html,body{
color: #fff;
}
```

when you want it to only one div just add:

```
color: #fff;
```

to it in the css

Answer (score 0):

```
color: #ffffff
```

for color white